# Supernode question

Tags: dc

I have run into a question while revising for my exam that I can't seem to wrap my head around.

[image]

I know I have to use a super-node. Which I have circled on he next image.

[image]

I don't understand why the solution does not include (V2 - V3)/2 which is the current into the super-node?

Are the two nodes merged to form one super-node?

Thanks in advance,

Daniel

Answer (score 1):

The supernode you circled is not the one the book's solution is referring to. If you look close you can see that:

$$\frac{V_1}{4}+\frac{V_2}{1}+\frac{V_3}{4}=0$$

is something like "the sum of the currents the three vertical resistors is zero". This of course is true since all the three resistors are connected to the lower node, and they are the only connected to it, that is just like saying that \$N_{1,2,3}\$ form a super node.

Your red circling leaves out \$N_2\$ while you should have included it too. If you do so you can easily understand why the current flowing through the horizontal R (why in hell aren't these components annotated by the way) is not included in that formula. If you want to include it you must also include the current flowing in \$N_{1,2}\$ and exclude the current flowing from \$N_2\$ to the lower node.

To answer your question: yes, they are merged.

That said, this equation of course is not enough to solve the circuit. You have a total of four nodes, an ideal voltage generator between two of them, one of the node would be the reference of course, that leaves you with two voltages to be found, so you'll need another equation to do so.